# How to make Table with Multiple coloumn and rows are added dynamicaly

Tags: android

I want to create a table in android with multiple column. I want 3-4 columns and I should be able to add the rows dynamically in the table. Can anybody provide me a sample code for this. I have tried by using the Base Adapter and List view But problem is that when I moving the List view Horizontal fix column will not move properly. It moves but fraction of delay. I dont know how to do above and from last one weak I am searching on this can any body please help me on this. If you want I can explain more briefly.

Answer (score 0):

As you say you have to make 3-4 columns and multiple rows so why you want to use tableview or Listview.You have to use `gridview`.Gridview provide you mechanism for multiple columns and  rows.

[Grid view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html)

If you don't want to use gridview then you can create a row in xml that has 3-4 columns and then you can inflate that row and you can add that row into the tableview.

[Layout Inflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dharmendra for your reply. I have not tried Grid view in the android I will tried out. and in your second option your telling me to use Layout Inflate method but I have tried this in base adapter but what is happening when I move the list view vertical It moves without any problem but when I move List view Horizontal my requirement is that My column has to move vertical as per the Column.

Comment: I did not get you what is  "when I move List view Horizontal my requirement is that My column has to move vertical as per the Column" ?

Comment: Actually I want to say my column has to move as per the rows. Suppose I have four column col1,col2,col3,col4 so when column is moving horizontally data below that column also has to move horizontally.

Comment: So that you have to use horizontal scrollbar outside of tableLayout.If you use Gridview then no need to use any scrollbar

Comment: Thanks Dharmendra I will try To use "Grid view" to create the Entry form but can you please confirm can I add rows dynamically because rows are not in my hand it comes dynamically.columns are fix but data which are come below are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);

TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setId(100);
tr.setOrientation(TableRow.VERTICAL);

TextView textvw01 = new TextView(this);
textvw01.setId(200);
textvw01.setText("blah");
tr.addView(textvw01);

TextView textvw02 = new TextView(this);
textvw02.setId(300);
textvw02.setText("Blah2");
tr.addView(textvw02);

/* Add row to TableLayout. */
tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Try it out,may work for u

Comment: Thanks a lot Richa for your reply. But In above Solution I don't How many rows because It is generating dynamically I don't know How many rows are their inside my table at run time.

Comment: i have given the simple format how to add rows in table layout,now its upon u how many rows u need to add at run time.....

Comment: It's not in my hand I don't know how many rows will come at run time. is their way to create row view dynamically.